# Table of content is not aligned in beamer Latex

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, align

[image]It might be a silly question, In my beamer representation the table of contents is not coming in a proper alignment I have searched it over the internet but nothing I get.
It is something which beamer align for us please help. I have used

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen}]{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
%\bibliography{Ref.bib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Ref.bib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb} {0.27,0.42,0.81}
\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\title[Phase transition study of Cobalt(Co)]{Phase transition study of Cobalt(Co) from HCP to FCC phase using \textit{Monte-Carlo} simulation of Axial Interaction Model}
\author{}
\institute{Project for JT-208}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you specify what the proper alignment should be? Everything looks fine to me if I add a couple of frames and sections.

Comment: I added my table of contents see density functional theory and Monte Carlo is not aligned properly now is it clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your (unfortunately incomplete) MWE, the only way I can reproduce your behavior is to define `\subsubsection{Density Functional Theory}` instead of `\subsection{Density Functional Theory}`. So this seems more like a typo than anything else. Just correct the `subsection` instead of `subsubsection` an it should be fine.

Note that not only the indentation is wrong but also the font size, which is another clue.

Also, your question title is pretty confusing, since it is an entry of the table of contents that is ill-aligned, rather than the table of contents itself.

See below

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen}]{beamer}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
%\bibliography{Ref.bib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Ref.bib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb} {0.27,0.42,0.81}
\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\title[Phase transition study of Cobalt(Co)]{Phase transition study of Cobalt(Co) from HCP to FCC phase using \textit{Monte-Carlo} simulation of Axial Interaction Model}
\author{}
\institute{Project for JT-208}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Motivation}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\section{Results}
\subsubsection{Density Functional Theory}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{Monte-Carlo simulation}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for pointing my idiotic error.

Comment: @problem_guy, if you had no problems, your nickname would be very inappropriate :)